# Where should i get all Jax-rs java implementation code in single place

Tags: rest

I am planing to perform benchmark analysis on all Java JAX-RS implementations.
Looking single place(link/git) where i get code example to save my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created example long back may be it will help -

**1.    Sun Jersey 1.8 RestWebservice –**

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>WebservicePrj</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebservicePrj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebservicePrj</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**HelloWorldService.java**

```
package com.example.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

**Track.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Track implements Serializable{

    String title;
    String singer;
//create getter & setter and override equals, hashcode & toString method

}
```

**JSONService.java**

```
    package com.example.rest;

    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


    import com.example.Track;

    @Path("/json/metallica")
    public class JSONService {

        @GET
        @Path("/get")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Track getTrackInJSON() {

            Track track = new Track();
            track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
            track.setSinger("Metallica");

            return track;

        }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }


}
```

**JerseyClientGet.java**

```
package com.example.client;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientGet {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/WebservicePrj/rest/json/metallica/get");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        System.out.println(output);


        //

         webResource = client
                   .resource("http://localhost:8080/WebservicePrj/rest/hello/skhan");

                 response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                           .get(ClientResponse.class);

                if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                   throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
                }

                 output = response.getEntity(String.class);

                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                System.out.println(output);

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

**JerseyClientPost.java**

```
package com.example.client;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientPost {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/WebservicePrj/rest/json/metallica/post");

        String input = "{\"singer\":\"Metallica\",\"title\":\"Fade To Black\"}";

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
           .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                 + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**2.    Jboss RestEasy 2.2.1.GA RestWebservice –**

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>WebservicePrjResrEasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebservicePrjResrEasy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>WebservicePrjResrEasyName</name>
    <description>WebservicePrjResrEasy  des</description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>WebservicePrj</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
<!--    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.rest.JSONService</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**MessageRestService.java**

```
package com.example.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class MessageRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.example.rest;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Product implements Serializable {
    String name;
    int qty;
//create getter & setter and override equals, hashcode & toString method

}
```

**JSONService.java**

```
package com.example.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/json/product")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Product getProductInJSON() {

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("iPad 3");
        product.setQty(999);

        return product; 

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createProductInJSON(Product product) {

        String result = "Product created : " + product;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

**RESTEasyClientGet.java**

```
package com.example.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse;

public class RESTEasyClientGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {

        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(
                "http://localhost:8080/WebservicePrjResrEasy/rest/json/product/get");
        request.accept("application/json");
        ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getEntity().getBytes())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }

}
```

**RESTEasyClientPost.java**

```
package com.example.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse;

public class RESTEasyClientPost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(
            "http://localhost:8080/WebservicePrjResrEasy/rest/json/product/post");
        request.accept("application/json");

        String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";
        request.body("application/json", input);

        ClientResponse<String> response = request.post(String.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getEntity().getBytes())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**3.    Spring 3.2.2 RestWebservice –**

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebservicePrjSpring</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebservicePrjSpring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${jdk.version}</source>
          <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebservicePrjSpring</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.common.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**Shop.java**

```
package com.example.common.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class Shop {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String staffName[];
    private Date createdTS;
//create getter & setter and override equals, hashcode & toString method

}
```

**JSONController.java**

```
package com.example.common.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.common.model.Shop;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfc/brands")
public class JSONController {
    Map<Integer, Shop> shopData = new HashMap<Integer, Shop>();
    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setId(100);
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"DON1", "DON2"});
        shop.setCreatedTS(new Date());
        shopData.put(shop.getId(), shop);
        return shop;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/shop/get/onjson", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Shop getUpdatedShopInJSON(@RequestParam(value="json",required=true) String json,
            @RequestParam(value="name",required=false) String name) {

         ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         Shop shop =null;
         try {
             shop = objectMapper.readValue(json, Shop.class);
            if(name!=null && !name.equals("") && !name.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                shop.setName(name);
            }
            shop.setCreatedTS(new Date());
            shopData.put(shop.getId(), shop);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return shop;

    }

     @RequestMapping(value ="/shop/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public// @ResponseBody Shop
        ResponseEntity<?>

        createShop(@RequestBody Shop shop) {
            System.out.println("Start createShop.");
           // shop.setId(101);
           // shop.setName("DAN");
            //shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"DON5", "DON5"});
            shop.setCreatedTS(new Date());
            shopData.put(shop.getId(), shop);

            //return shop;
              return new ResponseEntity<>(shop, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/shop/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody List<Shop> getAllShops() {
          System.out.println("Start getAllShops.");
            List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<Shop>();
            Set<Integer> shopIdKeys = shopData.keySet();
            for(Integer i : shopIdKeys){
                shops.add(shopData.get(i));
            }
            return shops;
        }
}
```

**NetClientGet.java**

```
package com.example.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebservicePrjSpring/rest/kfc/brands/kfc-kampar");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }

}
```

**NetClientPost.java**

```
package com.example.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientPost {

    // http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebservicePrjSpring/rest/kfc/brands/shop/create");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String input = "{\"id\":105,\"name\":\"kfc-din\",\"staffName\":[\"DON9\",\"DON9\"]}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }

    }

}
```